# Configure New-WebHandler for all my Sites through PowerShell

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, iis

I have been trying to automate the creation of Managed Handlers and Script Map for all the sites that are being hosted in my IIS locally. I have been struggling to find the variable to append 'Executable (Option)' through powershell.

So far my Script looks something like this  :

```
Remove-WebHandler -Name sm1 -PSPath "IIS:\Sites";
Remove-WebHandler -Name sm2 -PSPath "IIS:\Sites";
Remove-WebHandler -Name mh1 -PSPath "IIS:\Sites";
Remove-WebHandler -Name mh2 -PSPath "IIS:\Sites";
New-WebHandler -Path "*.svc" -Name "mh1" -Verb 'GET,POST,DEBUG,HEAD' -Type "System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" -PSPath "IIS:\sites";
New-WebHandler -Path "*.xamlx" -Name "mh2" -Verb 'GET,POST,DEBUG,HEAD' -Type "System.Xaml.Hosting.XamlHttpHandlerFactory, System.Xaml.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" -PSPath "IIS:\sites";
New-WebHandler -Path "*.svc" -Name "sm1" -Verb 'GET,POST,DEBUG,HEAD' -Location "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" -PSPath "IIS:\sites";
New-WebHandler -Path "*.xamlx" -Name "sm2" -Verb 'GET,POST,DEBUG,HEAD' -Location "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" -PSPath "IIS:\sites";
```

I managed to remove and add all the Scripts successfully, however I am still facing the following error : 
https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/configure-the-iis-to-host-sitefinity-projects

I found out that I need to set the 'Executable' property as mentioned in the article under adding new Script Map. However, I am not able to find any documentation regarding this under : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/new-webhandler?view=win10-ps.

Any help on how to do it would be much appreciated.

Comment: `Set-WebHandler` has a `-RequiredAccess` parameter, which one of the valid values is `Execute`. Is it possible that's what you need?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/set-webhandler?view=win10-ps

Comment: My required access parameter is set to script by default. I tried setting it up to execute, but that still doesn't allow me to set the executable parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Add it under -ScriptProcessor like so:

```
New-WebHandler -Name YOUR_HANDLER_NAME -Path * -Verb * -Modules FastCgiModule -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\YOUR_SITE_NAME" -ScriptProcessor "c:\BLAH\BLAH-cgi.exe"
```